# Fetch API rejects with NetworkError when hosted on localhost (Firefox only)

Tags: javascript, firefox, fetch-api

I am seeing strange behaviour on Firefox when using the fetch API. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or if I have missed some documentation and what I am trying to do is not allowed.

If I host the page below on localhost, Firefox rejects the fetch and gives `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` I don't see any fetch requests in either the dev tools, or Wireshark. There doesn't seem to be any further debugging available to diagnose.

By "hosting on localhost", I mean hosted by a local web server (nginx in this case), rather than from the file system. The address bar shows "http://localhost/fetch_localhost_error.html" for example.

Hosting the same page at http://jsbin.com/yowebiyigi/edit?html,output or any other endpoint gives the expected output - the text appears in the div, and I see the fetch request being made in dev tools.

Chrome works correctly in both scenarios which implies both the localhost and remote server is configured correctly for CORS etc (but FF never seems to query the remote anyway).

I have tried both 48 and Nightly (51), both on Windows 7. Unfortunately I don't have access to any other OS right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <script>
 var result = fetch('http://www.randomtext.me/api/')

 result.then(
    function(response){
        return response.json()
    })
 .then(
   function (response) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = response.text_out;
   })
 .catch(
    function(error){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error;
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is pretty frustrating as I can't develop fetch-based solutions locally. Can anyone shine any light on what is going on?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Browser_compatibility you need to run version 34 as minimum. For me (running 33.1) it didn't work. After an update (now on version 48) it's working as expected.

Comment: Good point - I should have put this in the question. I have tried both 48 and Nightly (51), both on Windows 7. Unfortunately I don't have access to any other OS.

Comment: Seems to be a known behaivour. See https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/186 and https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/310. You may write your own polyfill or just avoid using fetch().

Comment: Thanks - I had seen those. The second one looks promising but was never followed up by the OP. I've raised a bugzilla ticket (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1295503) to see if the Mozilla guys can help and I'll update here if there's a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I had a configuration issue.

```
network.http.referer.XOriginPolicy
```

Should be set to 0 otherwise fetch will fail. I had it set to 1 for reasons I can't remember.

Comment: For anybody wondering what this is about - it's a Firefox configuration option available via `about:config`. It's `0` by default so this probably is not your problem.

Answer (score 20):

It was the damn AdBlock in my case. 3 hours wasted...
Hope someone will find this earlier.

Comment: More than 3 hours here, but gods knows how much more time I might have wasted if it wasn't for this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was uBlock Origin in my case, and I was able to see the blocking in its logger and whitelist from there.

Comment: In my case it was Privacy Badger

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that the APIs I was fetching locally (in my dev environment) had invalid certificates.  To solve this, I hit the APIs directly with Firefox and added security exceptions for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also double check that you are querying the correct end point. Just realized my port number was off by 1 character which is what waster